# Python threading.Condition() functionality across multiple processes

Tags: python, multithreading

I am writing a WSGI app using mod_wsgi.  I want to have the ability of many concurrent connections.  mod_wsgi spins up a new process for each request, making it impossible to use threading.Condition() for notifying a change from one thread to another thread.

I understand there is a few different ways to provide real time messaging between different running processes, (RPC, AMQP, d-bus, Jabber) but what I'm looking for specifically is something as close to the one-liners threading.wait() and threading.notifyAll().

When I wasn't using mod_wsgi, and just running multiple threads, here is essentially what I had working for me.  Obviously the two functions were run by different threads:

```
def put_value:
    # user has given a new value
    # update in DB, then notify any waiting threads

    my_condition.acquire()
    my_condition.notifyAll()
    my_condition.release()

def get_value:
    # user has requested to receive a new value as of this point
    # we will return a value as soon as we are notified it has changed

    my_condition.acquire()
    my_condition.wait()
    my_condition.release()
    # return some val out of the DB
```

Once again, what I'm looking for is something as close to the one-liners threading.wait() and threading.notifyAll().  I don't mind setting up some configuration and even something running in the background - but I have a fair amount of code that relies on the ability to stop and wait in the middle of a request until it is notified that it may continue.

Comment: The mod_wsgi module does NOT spin up a new process for each request. Certain configurations of mod_wsgi are however multiprocess and so request may not go to same process each time. If you use daemon mode of mod_wsgi with default of single process you will not have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

In the mod_wsgi configuration, set processes=1.  See http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIDaemonProcess for details.

Comment: I did see that, the problem is I don't want to limit myself to one process on one machine in the event that we grow.  It is definitely a solution, it just won't meet exactly what I'm looking for.